# Tensorflow not working: Could not load dynamic library 'nvcuda.dll'; dlerror: nvcuda.dll not found

Tags: python, tensorflow

I installed TensorFlow for CPU (Windows) a few weeks ago and it worked perfectly. However, today I tried to install it for GPU, but my GPU wasn't supported so I deleted the GPU version and reinstalled the CPU version. Now, when I try to run a simple convolutional neural network I get these messages and it just stops running:

[Error Messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRTJc.jpg)

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

These warnings occurred as `CuDNN.dll` is not found (which is used for running on GPU)

You can surpass these warnings using below code:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
```

OR

Just install the CPU version of `Tensorflow` :

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade TensorFlow
```

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68960205/is-it-there-something-wrong-with-tensorflow) similar resolved issue for more details.