# Is it there something wrong with tensorflow?

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

Hello I have being using `tensorflow` and `keras` for a while. I use this packages to build neural networks. As I work on CPU I was used to recive a message like this one:

> Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2

But now, after updating the packages I am getting the following warnings:

> 2021-08-27 18:48:09.068353: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found

> 2021-08-27 18:48:09.069154: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.

> 2021-08-27 18:48:46.432183: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'nvcuda.dll'; dlerror: nvcuda.dll not found

> 2021-08-27 18:48:46.432971: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:269] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)

> 2021-08-27 18:48:46.433910: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:169] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: LAPTOP-RR404INI

> 2021-08-27 18:48:46.434837: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:176] hostname: LAPTOP-RR404INI

> 2021-08-27 18:48:46.436222: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2

> To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.

Tensorflow works as expected, so I will like to now if these waranings are a problem and if they are how do I fixed it?

I have tried to fix the by uninstalling and intalling everything again using the following code from the issue [Installation of Keras and TensorFlow in R #1136](https://github.com/rstudio/keras/issues/1136) but I get the warnings anyway:

```r
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github(paste0("rstudio/", c("reticulate", "tensorflow", "keras")))
reticulate::install_miniconda() 
keras::install_keras()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing the warnings because the default tensorflow package is capable of taking advantage of a GPU device. When it is initialized, it looks for a GPU device + GPU drivers, and if it can't find them, it issues the warnings you see. If you don't have a GPU, or don't want tensorflow to use a GPU, they are safe to ignore.

If you find the warnings particularly annoying, you can install a CPU only version of tensorflow with:

```
keras::install_keras(tensorflow="cpu")
```

Or you can silence the warning by setting this environment variable before loading tensorflow:

```
Sys.setenv("TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"="2")
  # 0 = all messages are logged (default behavior)
  # 1 = INFO messages are not printed
  # 2 = INFO and WARNING messages are not printed
  # 3 = INFO, WARNING, and ERROR messages are not printed
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, regarding your second option I tried and did'nt work, I get this: `Sys.getenv("TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL" = "2")
Error in Sys.getenv(TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL = "2") : 
  unused argument (TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL = "2")`. I tried before and after loading tensorflow, I get the same output.

Comment: oops, that' supposed to be `Sys.setenv`

Comment: Your answer works, installed only the cpu version of tensorflow and get back to usuall warning, but you second work around does not seems to work. Could you tell me if this configuration supose to elimante also the default warning or just the new ones. I even try this: `Sys.setenv("TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"="3")` before and after loading tensorflow

Comment: The `TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL` must be set before Tensorflow is initialized, changing it after Tensorflow has initialized has no effect.