# Want Know Reason！！//Could not load dynamic library 'nvcuda.dll'; dlerror: nvcuda.dll not found

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

Why does this error occur when tensorflow has no gpu, but the model can still be run normally.

```
W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'nvcuda.dll'; dlerror: nvcuda.dll not found
W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:269] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
```

Error:-

```
2022-02-26 10:47:12.726011: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library invcuda.dll'; dlerror: nvcuda.dll not found
2022-02-26 10:47:12.727262: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:269] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does this error occur when Tensorflow has no GPU, but the model can still be run normally.

According to https://wikidll.com/nvidia-corporation/nvcuda-dll

> *"`Nvcuda.dll` a DLL (Dynamic Link Library) file, developed by NVIDIA Corporation, which is referred to essential system files of the Windows OS. It usually contains a set of procedures and driver functions, which may be applied by Windows."*

Since you have no GPU, presumably there are no NVIDIA drivers installed, and no `Nvcuda.dll`.  Presumably, the Tensorflow code is able to fallback to a mode where the model is run on the CPU.

You must have installed a Tensorflow for GPU version.  If you want to get rid of the (noisy) warning message, force install the CPU only version, or modify the logging levels.  For more details: see [Tensorflow not working: Could not load dynamic library 'nvcuda.dll'; dlerror: nvcuda.dll not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61262765)